# How to clear settings

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have stored directory/folder location as setting and if directory/folder doesn't exist then that setting should be deleted.

So for example `My.Settings.ProjectDirectory` may be "c:\folder1". I do a check to see if that folder exists with system (`System.IO.Directory.Exists`). If it doesn't exist I need to take the user back to a screen which asks the user to pick their project directory and I need to delete the `My.Settings.ProjectDirectory` by using the code below:

```
My.Settings.ProjectDirectory = Nothing
```

It seems like it is not deleting the setting and when I reload the program and `MsgBox(My.Settings.ProjectDirectory)` comes up with the previous setting.

So, if I write:

```
My.Settings.ProjectDirectory = Nothing
MsgBox(My.Settings.ProjectDirectory)
```

Then it will say it is nothing.

When I reload the program the previous saved `My.Settings.ProjectDirectory` string will magically re-appear.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Settings are stored in an XML file between sessions. At startup, the contents of that file are loaded into the `My.Settings` object and you use that object over the course of the session. Any time you get a setting you get it from that object and any time you set a setting you are setting it in that object. None of that affects the file.

In order to persist your settings between sessions, you have to save the `My.Settings` object. By default, that is done automatically when your app closes. You can also do it manually at any time or require it to be done manually in the project properties. If you simply end a debugging session in VS then I'm not sure that your app's shutdown code is executed, in which case the settings will not be automatically saved. You should end your session by closing the app as a user would, which will guarantee that settings automatically saved, assuming that your project properties are configured that way.

EDIT:

I just tested to confirm and clicking the *Stop Debugging* button or pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> does indeed cause the app to end without executing shutdown code and, thus, without saving settings. Close your application normally or explicitly call `My.Settings.Save` at some point and your settings should be persisted between sessions.

Comment: great i thought it may be associated with debugging but wasn't sure how to test it easily

Answer (score 1):

You missed to save settings.change code like as below:

```
My.Settings.name = Nothing        
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: There is not actually any need to call `Save` explicitly, given that settings are saved automatically at shutdown by default. You just need to make sure that you shutdown normally. That said, some people do prefer to save explicitly in case of a crash. Those of us who write software that never crashes don't have to worry about that. ;-)

Comment: thanks yes my.settings.save will be the solution i'm looking for. I'm very much a novice and picking back up on a program i half completed a few years ago so rusty ive always been, more rusty now. I use try statements too much just in case their is a factor i may have missed that could cause the program to crash even though i am often pretty sure ive got it all fine- so my.settings.save is something i'll definitely use.

Comment: @BAS, don't use explicit exception handling unless you definitely need it. If you think there could be an exception thrown somewhere, test and find out. For exceptions you haven't anticipated, handle the `UnhandledException` event of the application to enable you to shutdown or restart gracefully.